# HackerRank terminates my solution due to timeout

Tags: scala, performance, stack

I have to implement a queue using two stacks, here is the problem definition

> In this challenge, you must first implement a queue using two stacks.
> Then process  queries, where each query is one of the following
> types:
>
> 1 x: Enqueue element  into the end of the queue. 2: Dequeue the
> element at the front of the queue. 3: Print the element at the front
> of the queue.

This is my solution

```
    object Solution {
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.io.StdIn.{readInt, readLine}


  def init(): (Int => Unit, () => Int, () => Int) = {
    val stack = mutable.Stack[Int]()
    val interim = mutable.Stack[Int]()

    def move(source: mutable.Stack[Int], target: mutable.Stack[Int]): Unit = {
      while (source.nonEmpty) {
        target.push(source.pop())
      }
    }
    def enque(it: Int): Unit = {
      move(stack, interim)
      stack.push(it)
      move(interim, stack)
    }
    def deque() = stack.pop()
    def top()= stack.head

    (enque, deque, top)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String])={
    val (enque, deque, top) = init()
    val n = readInt()
    for(i <-1 to n){
      val t1 = readLine().split(" ").map(x=>x.toInt)
     t1 match {
       case Array(1, n) => enque(n)
       case Array(2) => deque()
       case Array(3) => println(top())
     }
    }
  }
}
```

there are 17 test cases. it runs fine on 10 test cases, other 7 give error "Terminated due to timeout".

what's wrong with my solution? I don't know if there is any fast stack in Scala

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the testing, it may help to have enqueue just push onto a stack and nothing else. Wait until dequeue or print front is called before popping and pushing to the second stack.

---

For a further optimization, keep track of the prior call. In the table below, enque is enq, front and deque are deq. For a "proper" implementation, there should be a queue class with both stacks and the prior call to support multiple queues with the same code.

```
prior  current
enq    enq            push to first stack
deq    enq            "move" second stack to first stack, push to first stack
deq    deq            peek | pop from second stack
enq    deq            "move" first stack to second stack, peek | pop from second stack
```

---

I looked at the challenge. I'm not sure if the following C++ approach would be allowed, but it would be relatively fast and only use a single stack, but one that is reversible in O(1) time. The trick is to use an XOR linked list for the stack, with the following functions, all of which have a time complexity of O(1): push_front(), front(), pop_front(), reverse(), the key one being reverse(). For each node in an XOR list, the link is the XOR of the links to the previous and next nodes. This requires that "iterators" to nodes include a previous and current pointer. For the challenge:

```
enque - push_front()
print - reverse() print(front()) reverse()
deque - reverse() pop_front() reverse()
```

Link to example code:

https://github.com/jeffareid/misc/blob/master/xorlist.cpp

Comment: thanks, I used your advice and after changing and submitting multiple times :) it worked!

Comment: @SimpleFellow - I updated my answer with a further optimization for repeated front or dequeue calls. The idea is to delay moving a stack until it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

After the suggestion from @rcgldr I modified the solution. the solution is not really functional way of doing things but at least it runs within the specified time.

*One thing to note is that if you submit the same answer at different times of day **OR** repeatedly submit the same solution,  you get different tests failing due to timeout. A bit strange! (must be a flaw in their system) and depending on your luck all tests are passed.*

The main difference between the original and modified one is the replacement of while with a for loop.

```
object Solution {

  import scala.collection.mutable
  import scala.io.StdIn.{readInt, readLine}


  private def init(): (Int => Unit, () => Unit, () => Int) = {

    val stack = mutable.Stack[Int]()
    val interim = mutable.Stack[Int]()
    var _top: Int =0

    def move(source: mutable.Stack[Int], target: mutable.Stack[Int]): Unit = {
        val i = source.size
      if(i>0){
          for(j <- 1 to i) 
            target.push(source.pop())
      }
    }
    def enque(it: Int): Unit = {
      if(interim.isEmpty)
        _top = it
      interim.push(it)
    }
    def deque(): Unit = {
      move(interim, stack)
      if(stack.nonEmpty)
        stack.pop()
      if(stack.nonEmpty)
        _top = stack.top
      move(stack, interim)
    }
    def top(): Int = _top

    (enque, deque, top)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val (enque, deque, top) = init()
    val n = readInt()
    for(_ <-1 to n){
      val t1 = readLine().split(" ").map(x=>x.toInt)
      t1 match {
        case Array(1, n) => enque(n)
        case Array(2) => deque()
        case Array(3) => println(top())
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is functional, and passes all tests ... (it'll die with an infinite loop if you try to dequeue or peek on an empty queue, because I am too lazy to check for corner cases, and it is not required anyway).

`in` accumulates all enqueues. `out` is lazily filled on demand whenever head is requested and it is empty. This way, enqueue is always O(1), dequeue and peek are O(1) on average (i.e., amortized O(1)).

```
object Solution {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = Source.stdin.getLines.tap(_.next)
    .map(_.split(" ").map(_.toInt)).foldLeft(Queue[Int]()) { 
      case (q, Array(1, n)) => q.enqueue(n)
      case (q, Array(2)) => q.dequeue()._2
      case (q, Array(3)) => q.peek().tap(q => println(q._1)).pipe(_._2)
    }
}

case class Queue[T](in: List[T] = Nil, out: List[T] = Nil) {
       
    def enqueue(t: T): Queue[T] = copy(t::in, out)
   
    def dequeue(): (T, Queue[T]) = out match { 
        case Nil => copy(Nil, in.reverse).dequeue()
        case h::tail => (h, copy(in, tail))
    }
    
    def peek(): (T, Queue[T]) = out match { 
        case h::_ => (h, this)
        case Nil => copy(Nil, in.reverse).peek()
    }
}
```